# Ruby/Selenium: How to click on a specific item that appears multiple times on a page

Tags: ruby, selenium

Here's the item in question - specifically that little caret:
http://screencast.com/t/NMPOM9Ok58q

As you can see there are multiples of those within the same page, they all have the same class etc.

I've tried several different routes and I've not been able to successfully click on that item.

I always want to click on the last of them present on that page (the number of them are dynamic so sometimes it's the 2nd one and sometimes it's the 6th - so referring to it with a specific number doesn't work)

Thanks for the help (my tests are written in ruby, using selenium and testunit)

Here are some things I've tried and a few variations of these as well (none of which actually produce a click on that item)

```
@driver.find_element(:class, "dropdown-toggle")[-1].click
@driver.find_element(:css, "(//*[contains,'a.dropdown-toggle')]").click 
element_present?(:css, "div.dropdown.open > a.dropdown-toggle").click
@driver.find_element(:css, "div.dropdown.open > a.dropdown-toggle").click
@driver.find_elements(:css, "caret")[-1].click
@driver.find_element(:css, "caret:last-of-type").click
@driver.find_element(:css, "div.dropdown.open > a.dropdown-toggle:last-child").click

@driver.find_element(:class, "span1").find_element(:tag_name, "a").click 
^ This one actually is the only one that clicks anything - but it only clicks the first carat.
```

Ultimately what I'm doing with this test is adding a filter, closing the filter window, re-opening the filter window, deleting the previous filter, adding a new one and closing the window.

Comment: Without seeing some code, we cannot tell you where you have gone wrong! We can only tell you that you are doing it wrong.

Comment: All right, I guess I was figuring you would just be able to tell me how to click on the last element of a page.

Comment: There are just one `div` with `class span1` ?

Answer (score 0):

how about using the CSS last child selector?

```
@driver.find_element(:css, "div.dropdown.open > a.dropdown-toggle:last-child").click
```

Comment: Dang, that certainly looked promising - absolutely nothing happens.  It just gets stuck on that step and ultimately times out

Answer (score 0):

If `<div class="span1">` is unique, you can try someth like:

```
@driver.find_element(:class, "span1").find_element(:tag_name, "a").click
```

ok, so, if you need to click all links, or just someth of it, then:

```
@links = @driver.find_element(:class, "span1").find_elements(:tag_name, "a")
```

`@links[0].click` - for first link

`@links[1].click` - for second link

etc.

Comment: Well, this actually clicks on the first carat in that box (not the last) but it's a step in the right direction since previous attempts weren't even able to click on any of them. Now if I can just figure out how to make it click the last one. Thank you

Comment: The issue with this is that the number of the last one always changes, it could be 4 it could be 9.  I can't specify a number - I need to specify the 'last' of it's kind.

Comment: @user3896725 it's very easy :) `@links.last.click`

Comment: @user3896725 can you give me a link to this web?

Comment: Ach, I feel like it's soo close! But I'm getting an element not found error now.

Comment: @Jen send your html :)

Comment: I wish I could - I'm sorry it's private (involves patient health data) Is there some other information I could provide? 

The website is based in HTML5 and Angular (I've run into problems previously especially with Angular since the pop-up windows are actually part of the main site so often times the windows include references to things that are a part of the page behind it)

Comment: @Jen this info doesn't help :( ok, which element not found?

Comment: @Jen can you send what attributes have this span and link?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how/where to get this information.  At the least, each on of the 'filter block's' contains them.  And I imagine there are some on the base page as well http://screencast.com/t/4yo3xAALhpx

Comment: @Jen open your web page in the browser, right click on the button/other element that you wanna use and "Inspect element" and see what your element contain